# Java Enums with Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics, enums, polymorphism, dao

I am switching gears from the interpreted world and I am trying to replicate a pattern I have used in the passed with great success but in Java.

The short of it is I am making a custom DAO (not using Hibernate or anything like that...ultimately it will be generic to handle different database engines (SQL and NoSQL). For  breaking into I am just using a MySQL/ Prepared Statements.

I want to basically define a DataMapper object that is responsible for mapping the field of a record to the fields in a database. I am trying to encapsulate any redundant logic for implementation details of transforming a type to the format the database expects. In the DataMapper I am trying to utilize an enum to list the fields:

```
public abstract class AbstractDataMapper<X> {

public static abstract class Field<Y> {
    protected String name;
    public Field(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public abstract void setValue(PreparedStatement stmt, int parameterIndex, Y value) 
        throws SQLException;
    public abstract Y getValue(ResultSet rset)
        throws SQLException;
}

public static class IntegerField extends AbstractDataMapper.Field<Integer> {

    public IntegerField(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(PreparedStatement stmt, int parameterIndex,
            Integer value) throws SQLException {
        stmt.setInt(parameterIndex, value.intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue(ResultSet rset) throws SQLException {
        return new Integer(rset.getInt(this.name));
    }
}
}


public class UserDataMapper extends AbstractDataMapper<UserDataRecord>{
    public static enum Field {
    entryId(new AbstractDataMapper.IntegerField("entryid"));

    AbstractDataMapper.Field<?> field = null;

    Field(AbstractDataMapper.Field<?> field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public AbstractDataMapper.Field<?> getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.field.getName();
    }
}
```

Obviously I tried to truncate the example to the meaningful parts.
The client code for exercising this

```
    public int insert(UserDataRecord user) {
    ...
        final String query = 
            "INSERT INTO users SET "
            + UserDataMapper.Field.entryId.getName() + " = ? ";

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        UserDataMapper.Field.entryId.getField()
            .setValue(stmt, 1, user.getEntryId());

       }
```

The issue I am encountering is with the last line. I am trying to use the generic object associated with the `entryId` enum to use it's special setValue function which handles getting the Integer into the proper format. My IDE is giving me the following error:
    The method setValue(PreparedStatement, int, capture#13-of ?) in the type AbstractDataMapper.Field is not applicable for the arguments (PreparedStatement, int, Integer).

I am sure I could get into a series of crazy typecasts...but at that point it would probably just be easier to expose the translation details.

Any ideas on getting this to work or a modification to this pattern that is better?

Answer (score 3):

`enum` can't be generic, so there's a problem for your case.

a simpler way of casting would be

```
public static enum Field {

public <T> AbstractDataMapper.Field<T> getField() {
    return (AbstractDataMapper.Field<T>)this.field;
}

// usage
UserDataMapper.Field.entryId.<Integer>getField()
```

The bigger question is, what's the point of using `enum` here? It would be much simpler to use some static public final fields.

```
public class UserDataMapper extends AbstractDataMapper<UserDataRecord>{

    public interface Fields {
        IntegerField entryId = new IntegerField("entryid"));

----

    final String query = 
        "INSERT INTO users SET "
        + UserDataMapper.Field.entryId.getName() + " = ? ";

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    UserDataMapper.Field.entryId
        .setValue(stmt, 1, user.getEntryId());
```

Comment: I was trying to use an enum so I could potentially iterate over the fields. Ultimately I was going to create a loop that inspected the record object if it had a value set for the specific field to dynamically build the query. Might be a moot point now :)

Comment: no problem to use reflection to find out all static public final variables.

Comment: Yeah I have been fighting the urge to use reflection. Considering this layer would be the LCD of interaction with any database - trying to avoid the performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the field in the enum is an `AbstractDataMapper.Field<?>` and not an `AbstractDataMapper.Field<Integer>`. When you call `setValue` on it, it expects some type that the compiler identifies as "capture#13-of ?", and not an `Integer` (or `int` which is autoboxed to an `Integer`).

If you are going to put fields with different, unrelated data types in the `Field` enum, then there's really no other way than to declare the `field` member variable as `AbstractDataMapper.Field<?>` (with the question mark), and  you're not going to avoid to cast it when you need to use it. You could add a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation to suppress the compiler warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
AbstractDataMapper.Field<Integer> field =
    (AbstractDataMapper.Field<Integer>)UserDataMapper.Field.entryId.getField();

field.setValue(stmt, 1, user.getEntryId());
```